# Why aren't things from /vendor being copied during bundle install?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rvm, bundler

I'm trying to install [bootstrap-sass-rails](https://github.com/yabawock/bootstrap-sass-rails).  I copied this line: `gem 'bootstrap-sass-rails'` into the `assets` group.  I ran `bundle install`.  I followed the directions on the README exactly, but Sass complained that it couldn't find 'twitter/bootstrap' - I fiddled around a bit with locating the file and then...

Here comes the confusing part -- the gem was installed fine (or so Bundler said).  But now there's nothing in my `/vendor/assets/stylesheets` directory!  I checked `git status` and no new Sass files (or anything else really) was changed except `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss` and `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`!  I thought maybe that gem was broken, but the same thing happened with [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass).

Why aren't my gems being installed correctly?

Full Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.12'
gem 'bson_ext'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'rb-readline', '~> 0.4.2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'chronic'
gem 'prawn-labels'
gem 'draper'
gem 'ruby-aaws'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.2'

group :assets do
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass-rails'
end

group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'thin'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'bourne'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'pry-doc'
  gem 'pry-debugger'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'pdf-inspector'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'guard-zeus'
  gem 'guard-livereload'
  gem 'debugger'

  gem 'rb-fsevent' if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /darwin/i
  if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /linux/i then
    gem 'rb-inotify' # Filesystem changes
    gem 'libnotify' # Desktop notifications
  end
end

group :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For "bootstrap-sass-rails" gem, the actual js and css files are located in gem's directory. They won't be copied to /vendor. And other gems do the same unless they provide a special `generate` task.

These directories will be included in assets' path. So when you mention `@import bootstrap`, Rails know where to search the files.

Comment: I see.  That gives me the error `File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap.`
Load path: Sass::Rails::Importer([redacted]/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss)
  (in [redacted]/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss)

Comment: @LaceCard, try to verify it in console: `Rails.application.assets.paths`. If the gem path included, the problem is not there.

Comment: Very interesting - it is in the path!  I also had to restart the server after my bundle install.  Now I'm not entirely sure what I changed, but I'm using `bootstrap-sass` now instead.

Comment: @LaceCard, yes, IMO "bootstrap-sass" is better and I use that as well. The names are so similar that I have not recognized it in question.